# Display title if custom post type has related course ID matching current course page ID

Tags: php, wordpress, for-loop, relationship, advanced-custom-fields

My current code below display the heading 'course instructors' at all times, when I need it to disappear when there are no course instructors.

What I need to happen is:

- Query all 'trainers' posts.
- Query the 'courses' field within each
  post.
- Check to see if the current course page ID exists within the
  'courses' field within any of the trainers posts.
- Display the
  trainers who have a course ID that matches the current course page
  ID.
- If any trainers has course ID that matches current course page ID then display heading 'Course Instructor'.

  ```
              <div class="instructors">

                  <?php
                  $trainersArray = array(
                      'post_type'      => 'trainers',
                      'posts_per_page' => -1,
                      'orderby' => 'name',
                      'order' => 'ASC'
                  );
                  query_posts($trainersArray);

                  $trainers = get_posts( $trainersArray );

                  ?>

                  <?php /*if($Course_ID):*/?>

                      <h3 id="trainers_heading">Course Instructors</h3><!-- only show this if there is instructors to show -->

                  <?php /*endif;*/?>

                  <div id="trainers_list">
                      <?php

                      foreach ( $trainers as $trainer ) :

                          $trainerID = $trainer->ID;
                          $trainer_courses = get_field('courses',$trainerID);  //SELECT THE CONNECTED COURSE'S CUSTOM FIELD
                          $fullName = get_the_title($trainerID); //GET THE NAME FIELD IN TESTIMONIAL POSTS
                          $trainerPage = get_the_permalink($trainerID);
                          $feedback_count = 0;

                          if( $trainer_courses ):

                              foreach( $trainer_courses as $trainer_course ):

                                  $trainerCourseID = $trainer_course->ID;

                                  if ($trainerCourseID == $Course_ID) : ?>

                                      <div class="instructor-block">
                                          <div class="instructor-profile ">
                                              <div class="profile-name">
                                                  <?php echo $fullName; ?>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="profile-link">
                                                  <a href="<?php echo $trainerPage; ?>">
                                                      View Full Profile
                                                  </a>
                                              </div>
                                          </div>
                                      </div><br><!-- Another BR Fernando? and it's not even in body text, its after a DIV, whats your problem? -->
                                  <?php 
                                  endif;

                              endforeach; 

                          endif; 

                      endforeach; ?>  <!--echo json_encode( $trainers ); -->

                      <? wp_reset_query(); ?>

                  </div><!-- .trainers_list -->
              </div><!-- .instructors -->
  ```

Comment: I have tried using different vars in the if statement which has been commented out. My php knowledge isn't great and just can't think right now, Friday afternoon makes it difficult. :(

Answer (score 0):

"If any trainers has course ID that matches current course page ID then display heading 'Course Instructor'".

Well you have to find out if any trainers have a course ID which matches the current course page ID before you decide if you display the heading obviously.

You may either do the foreach-loop twice or you just make an array containing $fullName and $trainerPage.

If the array contains elements you display the heading and make a simple foreach loop over the new array where you just do the output of the previously gained information about course instructors.

If I did not get the problem correctly please comment why.

Comment: I think you've understood, I just need work out how to write this so that I can achieve what you've stated. Thanks @Blackbam